# PHP Chunk_Split Function

Tags: php

I was making a short little program to split a long integer into smaller bits. At the moment, what it does is simply put one digit of the int orderly into an index of $arr.

```
$grip = 10001; $fade = '';
for ($i = 1; $i <= trim($grip); $i++) {
   $par = rand(0, 9); $fade .= "$par"; }
$arr = chunk_split($fade, 451, "\r\n");
echo $arr[1]; sleep(10);
```

I'm really hoping chunk_split does what I think it does and splits a string/int by a certain length.... Any help is thankfully accepted. :D

Comment: I'm trying to split the randomly generated number into chunks of 451 nunbers

Comment: Yeah. All it does is, as I stated, puts each digit of the variable into an index of $arr :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`chunk_split()`](http://php.net/chunk_split) doesn't return an array, but rather a string. If you want to use it, you would have to convert the string returned by `chunk_split()` into an array:

```
$arr = explode("\n", chunk_split($fade, 451, "\n"));
```

If you want an efficient solution though, you might want to consider something like:

```
$grip = 10001;
$fade = '';
$arr = array();

for ($i = 1; $i <= $grip; $i++) {
    $fade .= rand(0, 9);
    if ($i % 451 == 0) {
        $arr[] = $fade;
        $fade = '';
    }
}

if (!empty($fade)) {
    $arr[] = $fade;
}
```